# search filter in a dropdown list using wtforms, flask, javascript

Tags: javascript, python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I want to create a search field that auto completes from a dropdown list using wtforms. Like this article from w3schools:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_dropdown.asp

But the search box is not inside the dropdown and appears when I hover over the dropdown list.
therefore, the search field does not filter the dropdown list.

```
            <form method="POST">
                {{ form.csrf_token }}
                <div class='form-group'>
                    {{ form.alimento_select.label }}
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        {{ form.alimento_select(class_="dropbtn", onclick="myFunction()") }}
                        <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content"> 
                            {{ form.search(id="myInput", onkeyup="filterFunction()") }}
```

```
           <script>
                function myFunction() {
                        document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
                        }

                        function filterFunction() {
                            var input, filter, ul, li, option, i;
                            input = document.getElementById("myInput");
                            filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
                            div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
                            option = div.getElementsByTagName("option");
                            for (i = 0; i < option.length; i++) {
                                txtValue = option[i].textContent || option[i].innerText;
                                if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                                    option[i].style.display = "";
                                    } else {
                                    option[i].style.display = "none";
                                }
                            }
                        }
            </script>
```

```
#myInput {
                box-sizing: border-box;
                background-image: url('searchicon.png');
                background-position: 14px 12px;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
            }

            #myInput:focus {
                outline: 3px solid #ddd;
                }

            .dropdown {
                position: relative;
                display: inline-block;
            }
            .dropbtn {
                cursor: pointer;
            }
            .dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
                background-color: #3e8e41;
            }
            .dropdown-content {
                display: none;
                position: absolute;
                background-color: #f6f6f6;
                min-width: 230px;
                border: 1px solid #ddd;
                z-index: 1;
            }
            .dropdown-content option {
                text-decoration: none;
                display: block;
            }

            .dropdown-content option:hover {
                background-color: #f1f1f1
                }
            
            .show {
                display:block;
                }
```

Comment: Hi, can you show html generated of your code ?

Comment: Did you ever manage this?